# How to update Angular version in Module Federation Project (Micro frontends)

Tags: angular, angular10, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm working on an Angular project which has a micro frontend architecture using angular-architects/module-federation. We're currently on version 10.x.x and looking into updating the version of Angular. This is where we have a problem.
Project has TLA (aka shell) application and ~40 micro-frontends apps. Every application has it's own repo. Common dependencies are shared via module-federation mechanisms.

The question is how do we perform an update of Angular in all the SPAs? Application is huge enterprise project and we can't just do 40+ PR's and merge/deploy everything simultaneously for obvious reasons.
Please share your experience in doing such upgrades

We were looking into updating MFEs one by one, but this requires running few different versions of Angular in the TLA depending on the SPA currently loaded. This is really complicated approach.

Answer (score 0):

We are also working on Angular migration and migration module federation to native federation.

There is no option to do mi]gratin at one shot. You have to do all individual MFE's separately.